# Why do not use a numdef command within a caption?

Tags: macros

I would like to use the command `\32s16o2` defined as `\num\def\32s16o2{S$^{16}$O$_{2}$}` in within the `\caption{}` command, but an error message is generated: "Tex capacity exceeded, sorry". What is the problem?

Comment: I cannot understand why you don't use [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) (and `\caption{ ... \ce{S^{16}O2} ...}`) or [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) (and `\caption{ ... \ch{S^{16}O2} ...}`) – both packages explicitly designed to handle chemical compound formulas…

Comment: Don't use `numdef` ! It was removed from ctan with good reason. If you do use it it only allows numbers at the end not anywhere in the name. (assuming you mean this package https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/master/numdef )

Answer (score 4):

There are no circumstances in which you should use `numdef` package in a document. I put it in my github as a record of possibly interesting tex macro definitions, but it is not on ctan and shouldn't be used.

If you do use it, it only allows numbers at the *end* of the name, not at at any point.

The definition you have is essentially the same as a primitive definition

```
 \def\32s16o2{S$^{16}$O$_{2}$}
```

without using `numdef` at all, and works (defining `\3`) so long as this is the only string that ever follows `\3` .  If you try to define two such strings then only one will work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numdef}

\begin{document}

\num\def\32s16o2{S$^{16}$O$_{2}$} 
\num\def\32g12h5{G$^{12}$H$_{5}$} 

\32s16o2

\end{document}
```

does nothing useful and produces the error

```
! Use of \\3{2} doesn't match its definition.
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you find `\s16o2` easier to type than

```
$\mathrm{S}^{16}\mathrm{O}_{2}$
```

or, with `mhchem`, `\ce{S^{16}O2}`.

However, `\num\def` is ***very*** fragile.

If you insist with this idea, use `\protect` when in a `\caption` or other moving argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numdef}

\num\def\s16o2{\ensuremath{\mathrm{S}^{16}\mathrm{O}_{2}}}

\begin{document}

\s16o2 is nice

\begin{figure}

\caption{\protect\s16o2 is nice}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get the same with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\definecompound}[2]{\csdef{cmp@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\cmp}[1]{\csuse{cmp@#1}}


\definecompound{32s16o2}{\ce{S^{16}O2}}

\begin{document}

\cmp{32s16o2} is nice

\begin{figure}

\caption{\cmp{32s16o2} is nice}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Without `mhchem`, you can do instead

```
\definecompound{32s16o2}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{S}^{16}\mathrm{O}_{2}}}
```

Comment: @Roloka `\32s16o2` is the command `\3`  followed by the text  `2s16o2` you really do not want to use that syntax.

Comment: @Roloka The goal of my answer was to tell you ***not*** to use `\32s16o2`. Don't. Don't. Your life will be easier.

Comment: IMHO it should be `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}`.

Comment: @clemens RIght, I keep forgetting

Comment: Thank you! I will use \definecompound{32s16o2}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{S}^{16}\mathrm{O}_{2}}} and write \cmp{32s16o2}. Could you please help me how to define it in the bibtex file?

Comment: @Roloka Just use `\cmp{32s16o2}` also in the BibTeX file.